# Provide an example of each or explain why the request is impossible.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

(a) Two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, neither of which are continuous at $0$ but $f(x)+g(x)$ and $f(x)g(x)$ are both continuous at $0$

I said *possible* and let $f(x) = \{0: x<0,  1: x \geq 0 \}$, and $g(x) = \{1:x<0, 0:x \geq 0 \}$

(b) a function $f(x) $ continuous at $0$ and $g(x)$ not continuous at $0$ such that $f(x) + g(x)$ is continuous at 0.

I said *not possible* and I based that off the algebraic limit theory, unless it is possible. If so I would like an idea as to how.

(c) a function $f(x)$ continuous at $0$ and $g(x)$ not continuous at $0$ so that $f(x)g(x) $ is continuous at 0.

I said *possible*, I let $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=$$\frac{x} {x}$. $g(x)$ has an obvious discontinuity at $x=0$ but does it work that way?

(d) a function $f(x)$ not continuous at $0$ such that $f(x) + \frac{1} {f(x)}$
Is continuous at $0$.

I said *not possible* and for the same reason as *(b)*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't think that $g(x)=\frac{x}{x}$ can be used as a non continues function, while claiming at the same time that $f(x)g(x)=0\cdot\frac{x}{x}$ **IS** a continuous function.

Comment: @barakmanos So that one does not work. Are there functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for which $f(x)g(x)$ is continuous, or is it not possible?

Comment: b) if $f+g$ and $f$ are continuous at zero, then $(-f)+(f+g)=g$ is continuous at zero.   

c) Take $f=0$ the zero function and let $g$ be any function discontinuous at zero.

Comment: d) is possible. Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ for $x\lt 0$, and $f(x)=2$ for $x\ge 0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas For c, $x$ and $1/x$ work? Also there is a part e to this that asks for a function discont at 0 whose cube is cont at 0. Any ideas?